# In Twilio Studio Flow, is there a way to control file extensions, and limit file size of incoming message medias?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to limit the file extensions to jpeg/png of a particular size (7 mb for example).
Do I achieve this through Functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

MMS messages coming into Twilio are limited by the carriers and [you can see how big the images can be in the documentation here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018832773-Twilio-Programmable-SMS-Supported-File-Types-and-Size-Limits-for-MMS-Media-Messages). The total size of a message, including all attachments and text, should be no greater than 5MB.

So, you should not receive images that are larger than 7MB and they should be smaller.

Comment: Saw this resource separately. Thanks for confirming!